# Inkscape issue No PUBKEY

Tags: inkscape

Tried to install Inkscape but I'm getting this error.

GPG error: https://deb.opera.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D615560BA5C7FF72

I hope someone can help.

Comment: How are you trying to install Inkscape ? Are you using a ppa repository ? Which one ? or do you have a downloaded installer ?

Comment: That error has nothing to do with Inkscape, it has to do with a third party repo. You either need to import the gpg key for the repo or if the key is not available you need to contact the maintainer of the repository and have te key made available. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/55698/how-do-i-fix-no-public-keys-available-errors

Comment: I'm using the terminal. Tried adding ppa repository by this:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:inkscape.dev/stable  (after updating, still having the same error)

Tried this: gpg --export --armor 9BDB3D89CE49EC21 | sudo apt-key add - D615560BA5C7FF72 (after update, still same error)

Answer (score 0):

you forgot this step when adding the repo:

```
wget -qO- https://deb.opera.com/archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

This command adds the key. Note: `wget` needs to be installed.

Comment: I can't even install wget.

Reading package lists... Error!
E: Could not open file /var/lib/dpkg/status - open (2: No such file or directory)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.